# Create a new LabelDecl and add to Clang AST

Tags: clang, llvm, libtooling, clang-ast-matchers

I have a problem inserting `LabelDecl`. My goal is to create a goto statement in the program and to do that, first I need to create `LabelDecl` and add it to Clang AST.

There is an API to Create Label, but I am not able to get the IdentifierInfo.

```
static LabelDecl *  Create (ASTContext &C, DeclContext *DC, SourceLocation IdentL, IdentifierInfo *II)
```

My Only problem is getting the `IdentifierInfo *II` object. Any idea on this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem

```c
IdentifierInfo *Name = nullptr;
                     
string label = "your_label";  function scope. 
Name = &(*Context).Idents.get(label); // Use the context to get the identifier.
LabelDecl *labelDecl = LabelDecl::Create((*Context), Context->getTranslationUnitDecl(),stmt->getBeginLoc(), Name);
```